# How to fit the Expectation?

Tags: random-variables, expected-value, monte-carlo

Imagine I have the following approximation to the expectation of a random variable $Y$
$$
E[Y]\simeq \alpha x^{-\beta}
$$
for $x,\alpha>0$ and $0<\beta<1$. Now, imagine I have some average data $E[Y]$ which allows me to compute the theoretical fit parameter $x=(E[Y]/\alpha)^{-1/\beta}$. Then, upon a large number of simulations, I get the simulated average, $Y_s$, which satisfies $Y_s<E[Y]$, as seen

[image]

Naturally, I now would like to readjust my parameter $x$ by lowering its value, gradually, until I minimize $|E[Y]-Y_s|$. What is the best way to do this?

For example, iterating over $i$, one could define
$$
\frac{x_{i+1}}{x_i}=\frac{(E[Y]/\alpha)^{-1/\beta}}{(Y_s/\alpha)^{-1/\beta}} \Rightarrow x_{i+1}=x_i\left(\frac{Y_s}{E[Y]} \right)^{\frac{1}{\beta}}
$$
Since $0<\beta<1$, if $E[Y]>Y_s$, for example, then $x_{i+1}<x_i$ and we would hope $\frac{Y_s}{E[Y]}\to 1$. However, given my data, what I actually get is an oscillating fitting procedure, depending on the variable scale. Naturally, this depends on how $Y$ relates to $x$ but I would like to ask whether there could be a general way of fitting such parameters, solely based on the expectation approximation, and guarantee relatively fast convergence. Any ideas?

**Edit:** The random variable $Y$ is actually a function of a position $j$ as well (horizontal axis). In fact, at each position $j$, the expected value should be given by
$$
E[Y_j]\simeq \alpha x_j^{-\beta}
$$
I do not think this should matter for the answer, as each expectation is independent of other $j$'s, and the plot merely served a visualisation purpose. However, I should have made it clear from the beginning. Hope this is clear now.

Comment: What is the horizontal axis on your graph?

Comment: @fedja Thank you for pointing that out. Please see the edit.

Comment: Let me try to rephrase what you are saying and check if I get it right. You have a random variable $Y_x$ continuously changing with $x>0$. You want to find $x$ such that $EY=\alpha x^{-\beta}$. At each step you can make a sample, compute $EY_S$ and adjust $x$ from there. Is this right?

Comment: @fedja That is correct

Comment: Could you confirm the kind of samples you have available? You cannot draw single observations of $Y_x$ and then aggregate to find $E[Y_x]$? Instead, you decide on a location $x$ and get the estimate $E[Y_x]$ at that location? Is that correct?

Comment: @gg Yes, $Y_s$ is precisely a simulated average, over multiple observations.

Comment: @gg Could you provide a bit more explanation behind this approach? What would the iterative rule for $x_{n+1}$ be then?

Comment: Actually, it is still not clear to me what your problem is. If you know $E[Y]$ and you know that $E[Y]=\alpha x^{-\beta}$ why not solve directly for $x$? I.e. $x = (E[Y] / \alpha)^{-\frac{1}{\beta}}$. Why do you need to simulate and iterate? If you do not know $E[Y]$ how can you use it in the iteration?

Comment: @gg The problem is that such an expression is an approximation of the expectation. It is not actually equal to it. Ultimately, I want to first guess the parameter $x_0$ by such an estimate equation and then iteratively improve it by comparing it to the real averaged data. I am simply trying to find the most efficient way to do it.

Answer (score 1):

### Your Question

To make sure I have understood your question correctly, I summarize first what you know and what you want to find out.

1. You have a family of random variables $Y_x$ indexed by $x$ and a known quantity $\eta$ such that $\eta = E[Y_{x_0}]$ for a certain $x_0.$
2. But you do not know for which $x_0$ the equation $\eta = E[Y_{x_0}]$ holds, and this $x_0$ is what you are trying to find.
3. You can choose points $x_j$ and perform simulations which provide estimates $\hat{E}[Y_{x_j}]$ for the true mean $E[Y_{x_j}]$ as a whole. You cannot simulate single observations of $Y_{x_j}.$
4. You know (or assume) that $E[Y_x]$ can be approximated by the function $\alpha x^{-\beta}$ where $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are known.
5. Your iteration scheme based on the parametric approximation does not converge.

### Suggestion for solution

From what you provide, it is hard to say what goes wrong, possible reasons may be:

1. A bug in your programming.
2. The estimates $\hat{E}[Y_{x_j}]$ are too noisy.
3. The parametric approximation is not precise enough.

So I suggest you try something simple, the [bisection method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bisection_method) to find the root of $f(x) = \hat{E}[Y_{x}] - \eta$. Use your approximation (only) to determine the initial two points larger and smaller than zero, and then bisect the intervals as described in the Wikipedia article. You have not mentioned whether you know the variance of the estimate for $\hat{E}[Y_{x_j}]$ or whether you have control over it. The precision for $x_0$ is limited by the variance in $\hat{E}[Y_{x_j}]$. So, you have to stop if the variance in the estimate is larger than the difference in function value and, if you can, you may want to decrease the variance in line with the decreasing remaining size of the interval.

Based on your parametric function, you may want to try this also on the log-scale. This means that instead of finding the root of $f$ you find the root of the function $l(x) =\log\hat{E}[Y_{x}] - \log\eta.$ Sometimes this works better since $\log E[Y_x]$ should be (close to) linear.